# How to add sitemap of a blogger blog to Google webmaster tools?

Tags: sitemap

I have two blogs. Let's say http://name.blogspot.com/ and the other one is http://name2.blogspot.com/

For blog 1: While submitting sitemap to Google webmaster tool I selected the option and then added rss.xml at last. (http://name.blogspot.com/rss.xml)

Sitemap added successfully.

For blog 2: I followed the same procedure but it didn't work.

Then I tried to open the url (http://name.blogspot.com/rss.xml). The url was showing the atom feeds.

I tried same with the other blog but that url is redirecting to the feedburner feeds.

I think this is the reason why the other blog's sitemap is not getting submitted.

Help me with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Using FeedBurner with Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97090):

> Sitemaps expect the original domain of
>   the website in question to be found in
>   the feed in order to function
>   properly; these
>   feedburner.com-rewritten permalinks
>   will not work and then cause Webmaster
>   Tools to report a sitemaps error.

To fix it, change your sitemap URL from this:

`http://name.blogspot.com/rss.xml`

to this:

`http://name.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?redirect=false`

Comment: I feel that XML Sitemap submission is a very important task for SEO. That is why we need to submit SItemap of our URL. These tips are really helpful to us. Thanks.